# When I runing to Flask, I getting 'ImportError'

Tags: flask, debian

When i runnig Flask, i getting an error the:

```
root@8185205:~# flask run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 7, in <module>
    from flask.cli import main
ImportError: No module named flask.cli
```

what i did wrong?
I using python3.2.3 and debian(wheezy)

Comment: Did you use `FLASK_APP` to register your routes? if so, can you show how you did it?

Comment: @Tobin, "export FLASK_APP=/path/to/file/test.py"

Comment: The problem must certainly come from the registration of your application via `FLASK_APP`. As explained [here](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1847#issuecomment-223439632): The issue with doing e.g. `FLASK_APP=/path/to/file/test.py` is that, when you do e.g. `from . import app` from your route definition, you get e.g. `path` rather than `/path/to/file/test.py` – i.e. the module loader treats it as a separate module, and your routes get registered to the wrong Flask app.

Comment: @Tobin, thanks. It's worked for me